# The Style don't apply in a part of my code when I call it in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles, innerhtml

Hi everyone I'm  new in Web Development, even more in Javascript. I practice some Javascript to learn it in codepen.io, and I have an issue:

I've created an element with Javacript method `createElement()`=> the element is a div. I've styled it => it's working

I also created a textarea in my HTML file with a button, and put the value of the `<textarea>` into the div I created before (with Javascript).

The text/value (of the textarea) goes inside of the div (innerHTML) and it works fine for this part, but I want to apply some styles (with `.style="{some styles goes here}"`, or the method `classList.add("classX")`, but any of them is not working, like they all are ignored.

```js
let div = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.classList.add("test");

// Ici j'attrape l'INPUT
let inputText = document.querySelector("#txtarea");

//Ici j'atrappe le boutton => qui me permettra plus tard d'envoyer la valeur de ce que l'utilisateur aura écris dans l'input précédent au sen de la div à fond Jaune
let btn_send = document.querySelector("button");

//Processus d'envoi de la valeur 
btn_send.addEventListener("click", function() {
  //   Variable me permettant de mettre la main sur la valeur de l'input
  let value_style = inputText.value;


  //Intégration du text avec InnerHTML dans la div
  setTimeout
    (function() {
      div.innerHTML = value_style;
    }, 1000);


  // ajout de style au texte que l'on va envoyer dans la Div 


  //L'on vide l'input de sa valeur => pour renvoyer une  nouvellle valeur 
  inputText.value = "";
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  background: red;
}

.test {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 45vh;
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px outset black;
  margin: 11vh auto;
}

.style {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  color: #64a;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: #66e;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
  <header></header>
  <footer></footer>
  <label>Tapez quelque chose à afficher dans la div à fond jaune:</label>
  <textarea id="txtarea" placeholder="..."></textarea>
  <button>Appuyez pour envoyer</button>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: The codepen : https://codepen.io/ZakWebHunter/pen/ZEQvMLN

Comment: You can't add a style to plain text (that's what `innerHTML` is when it's in a JS variable). You've to add a class to the div itself, just like you've done when you created the div, i.e. put `div.classList.add("style")` inside the timeout callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.style` class isn't set onto anything. If you want to style the newly added text you would need to wrap it in something (in my example I wrapped it in a `span`).

You could create the `span` in the same way you did for the `div` with a `createElement`. In my example I just made it add a string into the innerHTML which will render as the element.

```js
let div = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.classList.add("test");

// Ici j'attrape l'INPUT
let inputText = document.querySelector("#txtarea");

//Ici j'atrappe le boutton => qui me permettra plus tard d'envoyer la valeur de ce que l'utilisateur aura écris dans l'input précédent au sen de la div à fond Jaune
let btn_send = document.querySelector("button");

//Processus d'envoi de la valeur 
btn_send.addEventListener("click", function() {
  //   Variable me permettant de mettre la main sur la valeur de l'input
  let value_style = inputText.value;


  //Intégration du text avec InnerHTML dans la div
  setTimeout
    (function() {
      div.innerHTML += `<span class="style">${value_style}</span>`;
    }, 1000);


  // ajout de style au texte que l'on va envoyer dans la Div 


  //L'on vide l'input de sa valeur => poir renvoyer une       vouvellle valeur 
  inputText.value = "";
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  background: red;
}

.test {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 45vh;
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px outset black;
  margin: 11vh auto;
}

.style {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  color: #64a;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: #66e;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
  <header>

  </header>


  <footer>

  </footer>
  <label>Tapez quelque chose à afficher dans la div à fond jaune:</label>
  <textarea id="txtarea" placeholder="..."></textarea>
  <button>Appuyez pour envoyer</button>

</body>



</html>
```